# keep delimiter "-" with after the string is split("-")

Tags: java

I was wondering what's the best approach to keep the delimiter with the aftermath `String` after its split("-").

So here is the code:

```
String word = "abc -def ghi -jkl -mno pqr";
String[] strArr= null;
strArr = word.split("-");
...
here we iterate through array
```

it will print:

```
abc
def ghi
jkl
mno pqr
```

but I want to keep the delimiter and it should look something like:

```
abc
-def ghi
-jkl
-mno pqr
```

One way is, while iterating, to concatenate the "-" delimiter, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: The delimiter actually seems to be the space in your example

Comment: Depends: what's the correct output with input `"abc def -ghi -jkl"`?

Comment: @ajb there might be a time where there could be a space in between strings without delimiter which is why I specifically want it with `"-"` delimiter.

Comment: @Simple-Solution Yep, thought so.  I think splitting on a lookahead is what you want.  If you don't want to preserve the spaces before the `-`, then either `split(" +(?=-)")` or `split(" *(?=-)")`, depending on whether you want `-` with _no_ spaces before it to be a delimiter.

Comment: @ajb I want it with no spaces before if that what your asking.

Comment: @ajb also can you explain what this part is telling splitter `split(" +(?=-)")`?

Comment: The delimiter is one or more spaces, followed by a _lookahead_ pattern that matches `-`.  The effect is that the delimiter will match a space, or spaces, that is _followed by_ a hyphen, but the hyphen itself doesn't become part of the delimiter because of _lookahead_.  The spaces do become the delimiter, so they get removed when the resulting substrings are created.  But the hyphen isn't part of the delimiter so it gets to stay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split on the space :

```
strArr = word.split(" ");
```

Comment: There might be time where there might be a single block with spaces which is why I had it split by `"-"`